# Crystal Reports não lê a tabela quando enviado pelo aplicativo mas lê a tabela no Editor do Crystal

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, eu estou com um erro bem estranho, eu tenho um relatório no Crystal Reports que o mesmo mostra os dados de uma tabela (não há nenhuma forma ou parâmetro no relatório ele somente mostra os dados de uma única tabela), o erro é o seguinte, eu estou no editor do Crystal Reports e aperto F5 ele atualiza a tabela normalmente, vamos supor que esta tabela tenha 3 linhas e dentro do editor elas aparecem corretamente, mas quando estou no código em C# e executo o programa com o seguinte código:

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

cryRpt.Load(@"Reports\Stock.rpt");

cryRpt.DataSourceConnections[0].IntegratedSecurity = false;

cryRpt.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(SQLController.Server, SQLController.DataBase, SQLController.UserId, SQLController.Pass);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;

crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Acontece que o mesmo só mostra as informações que foram apresentadas quando eu salvei o relatório lá no editor do Crystal Reports.
Esta tabela é gerada por outro sistema ou seja ela é dinâmica.
Quando eu criei o relatório e naquele momento a tabela tinha 3 linhas quando eu vou fazer pelo código ela só aparece as 3 linhas, mas se eu for na tabela (lá no SQL Server) ela nesse momento tive 10 linhas o relatório só ira mostra 3, ai quando eu vou no editor do CR e aperto F5 ele mostra as 10 linhas se eu salvar o relatório e for para o C# e nesse momento a tabela estiver com 7 linhas o mesmo só vai mostrar as informações com 10 linhas que foi da última vez que ele foi salvo no editor do CR, ou seja o relatório não esta atualizando, o que devo fazer?

Answer (score -1):

Depois de tanto procurar achei a resposta, lá no editor do CR antes de salvar tem que fechar a aba de visualização, ai resolve o problema.

Comment: Tem uma opção no crystal reports. Arquivo -> Opções -> Gerando relatório -> Salvar Dados com o Relatório. Desmarque está opção.